# Increment/Decrement variable on button - PHP Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, increment, decrement

I have a like/unlike button and number of like field and it echos a variable that gets number of likes as follows:

PHP-HTML:

```
<span>likes: <?php echo $row['likes'];?></span>
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-custom btn-sm liketoggle" name ="like">

//Printing 'Like' if its been liked by user, and 'Unlike' if not liked by user
<? $qid = $row['Question_ID']; $query2 = "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE 
       user_id='$user_id' and qid = '$qid'";
      $results2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($results2) == 0){ echo '<span>Like</span>';} 
      else{echo '<span>Unlike</span>';}?></button>
```

Javascript - To toggle like/unlike:

```
$(".liketoggle").click(function () {
            $(this).find("span").text(function(i, v){
               return v === 'Like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'
               return v === 'Unlike' ? 'Like' : 'Unlike'
            })
        });
```

Is there I way I can increment the number of likes ($row['likes']) when user hits on like, and the same way decrements when unliking?

Comment: Welcome to SO. 

In short, no. You are trying to mix server side code and js code. You'd need to send the new variable to the server for it to render a new page, or you could implement ajax or something dynamic like that. the best approach would be to make a rest endpoint for you to call any time you want to increment or decrement.

Comment: AJAX is a pretty broad topic, but the basics are pretty easy with jQuery.  Look up `$.post` for information on what you need to do.  AJAX wise, and look into JSON and json_decode for more server side information.  JSON is just JavaScript Object Notation.  It's basically a way of encoding structured data so it can be passed in a we request to the server and back when using AJAX.  JSON basically replaces the X in AJAX (Asynchronicity JavaScript  and XML) but hardly anyone uses XML these days.  XML, like JSON is a way to pass structured data, but its more HTML like (HTML is a derivative of XML)

Comment: Plus AJAX sounds better then AJAJ  ... lol.  Don't be afraid to post another question, or search the stack overflow pages for AJAX if you get stuck.  When you go to update it you can do something like this `REPLACE INTO likes SET like=0 WHERE question_id=? AND user_id=?`  with replace you don't have to decide between insert and update as long as your rows are unique.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

Comment: The AJAX is doing its job by updating the likes in the database but the number of likes stays the same in the front end and I want the number to be incremented without refreshing the page. @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: How I can use the $.post in this case? @ArtisticPhoenix

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to change the number.

```
<span>likes: <span class="likes-count"><?php echo $row['likes'];?></span></span>
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-custom btn-sm liketoggle" name ="like">

//Printing 'Like' if its been liked by user, and 'Unlike' if not liked by user
<?php $qid = $row['Question_ID']; $query2 = "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE 
       user_id='$user_id' and qid = '$qid'";
      $results2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
      if(mysqli_num_rows($results2) == 0){ echo '<span>Like</span>';} 
      else{echo '<span>Unlike</span>';}?></button>
```

JS:

```
$(".liketoggle").click(function () {

            $(this).find("span").text(function(i, v){
               return v === 'Like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'
               return v === 'Unlike' ? 'Like' : 'Unlike'
            });

            var likes = $('.likes-count').text();
                likes = likes ? parseInt(likes) : 0;

             if($(this).find("span").text() == 'Like') likes++;
             else if(likes > 0) likes--;

             $('.likes-count').text(likes);

        });
```

Comment: Its incrementing decimal numbers and its not incrementing by 1. Please advise.

Comment: You have to know what number is a `like` in order to use my method. Otherwise you will need to do an ajax call to calculate the likes before printing them.

Comment: How is it possible with AJAX? I'm not much familiar with AJAX, How I can call it in my case?